# Subsonic 3 - Update NullReferenceException

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I am using Subsonic v3.0.0.3 with the Linq templates. I am attempting to update a record in a SQL Server Express database with the following:

```
var db = new MyDB(Constants.Database);
db.Update<Contact>()
  .Set(d => d.FirstName == contact.FirstName)
  .Where(d => d.Id == contact.Id)
  .Execute();
```

I am receiving a `NullReferenceException` when this line is executed. The stack trace is as follows:

```
   at SubSonic.Query.Update.GetCommand()
   at SubSonic.Query.Update.Execute()
```

Any chance that someone may be able to suggest what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm - I would say to make sure the connection string is present (I'll be fixing the error message for missing connection strings in the coming weeks) other than that - this looks like an issue - would you mind posting at Github?

Comment: It should be throwing a meaningful error if the connection string is null: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/blob/d258f4793f0fffae3cf0fa707fddbeb7f56b277c/SubSonic.Core/DataProviders/ProviderFactory.cs#L31

Comment: It seems not to be a connection string issue - as I'm getting data from the database using similar conventions. I will certainly lodge it over at github.

Comment: Thanks - I'm getting some buggy code contributions that I need to watch more closely - also I need some more tests :)

Answer (score 1):

I did a simple update which give me an NullReferenceException

```
FarmDB db = new FarmDB();
db.Update<UserInfo>().Set(x => x.phone == "13679178184").Where(x => x.name == "marship").Execute();
```

After step into the code, I found the line in Query/update.cs L186

```
internal Setting CreateSetting(IColumn column, bool isExpression)
{
    Setting s = new Setting
    {
        query = this,
        ColumnName = column.Name,
        ParameterName = (_provider.ParameterPrefix + "up_" + column.Name),
        IsExpression = isExpression,
        DataType = column.DataType
    };
    ...
```

The `ColumnName = column.QualifiedName` should be `ColumnName = column.Name`.

After correct this, update runs well. Hope some one can check this.