# Subsonic 3: Update<T> problem

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I am using SS 3.0.0.3 ActiveRecord. This query:

```
new Update<BillDetail>(provider)
    .Set(bd => bd.DivisionDetails == divisionDetails)
    .Where(bd => bd.BillNumber == documentId && bd.IsInvoice == true);
```

produces this SQL:

```
UPDATE `BillDetails` 
 SET `DivisionDetails`=@up_DivisionDetails
 WHERE `BillNumber` = @0
```

Where did the IsInvoice part go? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed in 3.0.0.4.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem in previous releases but it was fixed - you sure you're using 3.0.0.3?

Comment: I tried both 3.0.0.3 and the current developer build.

In 3.0.0.3 the query will throw a NullReferenceException.
In the current developer build the query returns the above SQL.

Comment: I think the NullReferenceException issue is the same as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178406/subsonic-3-update-nullreferenceexception

Comment: Downloaded a fresh master copy of SS. As on today, this bug is yet to be fixed!!